# Texto de quando a pergunta foi feita há x anos e y meses atrás está sem tradução

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Estava navegando em uma pergunta antiga, quando noto próximo ao canto superior direito da tela isso:

<kbd>[image: 1 years, 1 months ago]</kbd>

Observe o **1 years, 1 months ago**.

Fui numa pergunta recente e apareceu corretamente:

<kbd>[image: 7 dias atrás]</kbd>

Até 1 ano atrás aparece certo:

<kbd>[image: 1 ano atrás]</kbd>

Procurei uma pergunta dos primórdios desse site e veio isso:

<kbd>[image: 4 years, 2 months ago]</kbd>

Uma um pouquinho mais nova veio certo:

<kbd>[image: 4 anos atrás]</kbd>

Ou seja, quando a pergunta foi feita há x anos e y meses atrás, o texto aparece em inglês.

Ah, um outro detalhe: Por quê "ativas" ao invés de "ativa"?

Comment: Tem outro problema também que quando eu vou num perfil de um usuário o tempo que ele é membro da comunidade também aparece em inglês, [veja só](https://i.imgur.com/WFkWmad.png).

Comment: Parece que o pessoal do desenvolvimento tá alterando as chaves do dicionário porque tem várias traduções que estão ficando  'zoadas'.

Comment: @JuanM Use a tag [status-pronto] no lugar de [status-ready] por aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essas traduções foram atualizadas! Obrigado por denunciar isso.

Comment: Ainda acontece para mim. Tem que esperar o próximo build?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim, exatamente.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acabei de confirmar as mudanças, elas estão agora implementadas.